# Making complex UI easier - User License

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, design-patterns

- I have an admin portal for a Staff / Tech Support to check USB Dongle
  license information and help customers solve problems
- The client interface is much simpler, but due to legacy data and how
  the hardware was built years ago I can't reduce these fields for the
  staff users
- If the account has multiple licenses, then I display a series of
  accordions, so each one is a license/dongle[![enter image description here]

I moved the important information to the top.

Some options I thought to improve user experience:

1. Contextual (can hide some fields in some cases, but my dev says it
   could be very expensive), like Network licenses could be hidden if
   the product level is not network, the same thing for lease
2. An inexpensive option could be tabs or nested accordions, but I
   wonder whether those are really user-friendly
3. Working on visual hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

This is a new iteration of the UI, putting the buttons closer to the editable field and reducing vertical space

Another idea with some image placeholders

**Third revision**

After finalizing the UI I realized some problems and came with a new solution:
-If the page has multiple dongles it can't use search (within the page) properly because it will have to retrieve all the data on the accordions.

-I've tried adding/expanding the UI with a extra pane on the left as a test, but if you have few licenses on the screen it looks strange. The scrolling is also not ideal

**Fourth revision**

1. This layout requires no scrolling if the search is used on the left
   pane
2. It will not look strange if you have multiple dongles
3. The editable fields will be hidden (pen) in some cases and displayed
   with hover just like in Hubspot CRM

Answer (score 0):

I deal with legacy challenges daily and most of the time this solution is exactly how I would handle it. Our users have been pleased with the decluttering.

The edit pencils don't look very clickable though.  I would recommend making them your accent color (the blue) since your other buttons are also blue.

Comment: Hello Brett, in that case the ones with the buttons

Comment: the ones with the pencil or button, so it is not clear enough? any suggestions?

Comment: I updated my answer.  I didn't see the revision until just now.  I think the pencils need to look more clickable.  Make them blue like the buttons on the page.

Comment: Third Revision is uploaded

Comment: Consider maybe containing the edit buttons, but I think what you have is pretty good.

Comment: Parson, what do you mean about containing edit buttons?

Comment: Having them have an outline like your delete button at the bottom.  I think that is more my opinion though.